# Is it safe to override `release` for debugging?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, debugging, memory-leaks, release

Sometimes I need to find out if an object will really be released. I could use Instruments of course, but that takes much time, and I have to search into millions of objects, so I used to do this:

```
-(void)release {
    NSLog(@"I'm released");
    [super release];
}
```

But the problem is: **is this safe to do**? Can I get any problems when I override `-(void)release`. Also, is it really `void`? And what if I build my application for distribution, but per accident leave it there? Or is it just safe? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "really released"?  Do you think that sometimes [foo release] doesn't cause the release message to be sent?

Comment: @JeremyP `[[[foo alloc] init] autorelease];`??

Comment: I see.  You don't want to see if the release method works, but if the object ever gets released.  It may get retained and released many times over its lifetime, so debugging the release method is probably not that useful.  You probably want to check out Laurent Etiemble's answer below.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's fine, but please restrict it for debugging only.

---

It's not `void`, but `oneway void`.

```
-(oneway void)release {
    NSLog(@"I'm released"); // <-- remeber the @.
    [super release];
}
```

Note that if you only override this for NSObject, then the `-release` messages sent to "toll-free bridged containers" (e.g. NSCFArray, etc.) will be missed since they've  also overridden `-release` to forward to `CFRelease`.

Answer (score 5):

The release message only decrements the reference count of the instance.

If you want to know if the instance has been released, then the best is to override the dealloc message:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"I am deallocated");
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Use it wisely.